# EOF exercise 1-6 K&R The C programming language

Tags: c, eof, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

This is taken directly from the K&R book:

> The precedence of `!=` is higher than that of `=`, which means that in the absence of parentheses the relational test `!=` would be done before the assignment `=`. So the statement
>
> ```
> c = getchar() != EOF
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> c = (getchar() != EOF)
> ```
>
> This has the undesired effect of setting c to 0 or 1, depending on whether or not the call of getchar returned end of file. (More on this in Chapter 2.)
>
> **Exercise 1-6.** Verify that the expression `getchar() != EOF` is 0 or 1.

I am having trouble understanding how to do this exercise as well as understanding what is going on with the blockquoted paragraph.

I know that EOF is a symbolic constant of type int and usually holds the value -1. Since a negative valued int can never hold the same value as char when it makes a comparison it needs to be promoted to int which then somehow signals the end of file.

I also get that without the parenthesis specified above the comparison `!=` is done before the assignment but what does this actually mean? What is it that happens to that function? Also I printed the value of EOF and it was -1 what does the exercise mean when it says verify it is 0 or 1?

Comment: You should verify that the value of `(getchar() != EOF)` is 0 or 1. The sentence about the parentheses mean that without the parentheses, it is the same as `c = (getchar() != EOF)`.

Comment: "Since a negative valued int can never hold the same value as char": wrong. `char` vales can be negative. What happens is that the result of `getchar()` is first, internally, converted to `unsigned char`; then, the result of that conversion is converted to `int` --- and it is this last conversion that (*basically*) can never be negative.

Comment: If you store the result of `getchar` in a `char`, it's implementation defined whether it works or not when checking against `EOF`. If `char` is signed, it may be ok -- but it will misinterpret the value of 255 as EOF, and it's not good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saying that:

`c = (getchar() != EOF)`

means read a character from `stdin`, then compare it against EOF. The result of this is 1 if true, 0 if false. That result is then assigned to `c`. The character that was read is lost, hence 'undesired effect'.

It wants you to run this yourself in this way to see how you can produce 0 and 1 by sending EOF vs. any other character.

Comment: @Prafiate In the same book on page 42 of chapter 2 they also go a bit more into detail saying "Similarly, it would be unfortunate if c were tested against EOF before getchar is called; therefore the call and assignment must occur before the character in c is tested." and then they give an example with better clarification as to why precedence is important.